# Deriving diagonal approximation of Hessian in a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, hessian-matrix

Consider the equations relating to the diagonal approximation for the hessian matrix for a neural network in *"Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning - Christopher Bishop"* *(on pg. 250 eq. 5.80)*

1. $\frac{\partial^2 E_{n}}{\partial w_{ji}^2} = \frac{\partial^2 E_{n}}{\partial a_{j}^2} z_{i}^2$
2. $\frac{\partial^2 E_{n}}{\partial a_{j}^2} = ({h}'(a_{j}))^2 \sum_{k} \sum_{k'} w_{k'j}w_{kj}\frac{\partial^2 E_{n}}{\partial a_{k} \partial a_{k'}} + h''(a_{j})\sum_{k}w_{kj}\frac{\partial E_{n}}{\partial a_{k}}$

$a_{j}$ - *input to a unit j*

$h$ - *activation function*

$z_i = h(a_i)$ *i.e output of a unit i*

$w_{kj}$ - *edge from j to k*

I am interested in how *eq. 2* follows from:

$\frac{\partial E_{n}}{\partial a_{j}} = h'(j)\sum_{k} w_{kj}\frac{\partial E_{n}}{\partial a_{k}}$

*where k runs through all the units to which unit j **directly** sends a connection to (eq 5.56, pg 244).*

In particular, I am getting a different result for the first term on the RHS of *eq. 2*, i.e

3. $({h}'(a_{j}))^2 \sum_{k} \sum_{k'} w_{k'j}w_{kj}\frac{\partial^2 E_{n}}{\partial a_{k} \partial a_{k'}}$

So, *eq. 3* should follow from:

4. $h'(j)\frac{\partial }{\partial a_{j}}\sum_{k} w_{kj}\frac{\partial E_{n}}{\partial a_{k}}$

Following is the way how I tried to derive *eq. 3* from *eq. 4* using the chain rule of differentiation:

$h'(a_{j})\frac{\partial }{\partial a_{j}}\sum_{k} w_{kj}\frac{\partial E_{n}}{\partial a_{k}}$

$= h'(a_{j})\sum_{k}\frac{\partial a_{k}}{\partial a_{j}} \frac{\partial }{\partial a_{k}}w_{kj}\frac{\partial E_{n}}{\partial a_{k}}$

$=h'(a_{j})\sum_{k}h'(a_{j})w_{kj}\frac{\partial }{\partial a_{k}}w_{kj}\frac{\partial E_{n}}{\partial a_{k}}$

*Used:*

$(a_k = \sum_jh(a_j)w_{kj}) \wedge (\frac{\partial w_{kj}}{\partial a_j} = 0 )\rightarrow \frac{\partial a_{k}}{\partial a_j} = h'(j)w_{kj}$

So what remains to be shown is:

5. $\sum_{k}w_{kj}\frac{\partial }{\partial a_{k}}w_{kj}\frac{\partial E_{n}}{\partial a_{k}} = \sum_{k} \sum_{k'} w_{k'j}w_{kj}\frac{\partial^2 E_{n}}{\partial a_{k} \partial a_{k'}}$

which should complete the proof.

**QUESTION 1**

How to establish *eq. 5* ?

One may want to use:

$\frac{\partial a_k} {\partial w_{kj}} = z_j$

**QUESTION 2**

If

$y = f(x_1, x_2,...)$

then, is it *always* true that

$\frac{\partial y} {\partial x_k} = 1 / \frac{\partial x_k} {\partial y}$